# Shiny Application: Add logo to each choice of selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I create a shiny app and I need to add a language option. I would like add a selectizeInput like :

```
selectizeInput("language",
                         "Select language:",
                         choices = c("English"="en","Français"="fr"),
                         selected = app_default_languague, multiple=FALSE, width = '70%'
                         )
```

but with flags in front of each country. Flags logo are in "www/" directory. Do you know how i can make this please ?

There is an example in Rstudio gallery but i don't understand it ....
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-rendering-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

`selectizeInput` is based on the Javascript library [selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) which has powerful settings including templates to render your own options and the selected item.

In order to do that you have to use a bit of Javascript code. This code is stored in `rendersjsItem`. That is a Javascript function that generates and returns a piece of HTML like this:

```
<div class="option">
  <img width="25" height="25" class="flag" src="fr.svg" />
  French
</div>
```

This assumes that your files are located in the *www* folder with the country code as name, e.g. "fr.svg". The example below specifies names and country codes in the vector `countries`.

All you need to do is take `rendersjsItem` and use it as `render` option for the `selectizeInput`. If you want to change the styling you can modify the CSS of the `flag` class.

**Full Solution**

```
library(shiny)

countries <- c(German = "de", Czech = "cz", French = "fr")
app_default_languague <- "cz"

# Assuming the flag icons are directly in the 'www' folder with names "de.svg", "cz.svg", etc.
rendersjsItem <- 
  I("{
      option: function(item, escape) {
        return '<div class=\"option\"><img width=\"25\" height=\"25\" class=\"flag\"' +
            'src=\"' + item.value + '.svg\" />' +
            item.label + '</div>';
      }
    }")


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    # Add CSS to format the language selection options with flag + text
    tags$style(HTML(".flag {height:24px; width:24px; margin-right: 12px}"))
  ),
  title = "Selectize Test",
  selectizeInput("language", "Select language",
                 choices = countries,
                 selected = app_default_languague, multiple=FALSE, width = "70%",
                 options = list(
                   placeholder = "Type a language name, e.g. German",
                   render = rendersjsItem
                 )),
  textOutput("SelectedLanguage")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$SelectedLanguage <- renderText(input$language)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Side Note**

The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) [recommends that flag icons should not be used to indicate languages](https://www.w3.org/International/techniques/authoring-html#language). There are multiple reason. Instead, use the name of the language in it's target language, i.e. do not write "German" but "Deutsch". Examples: Deutsch, English, Español, Français, Italiano, ...

See also [ux.stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11891/should-i-use-country-flags-in-language-selection-fields).